# Angular-How to use spread operator in angular html template

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a simple angular app with a module and a component. For the sake of simplicity let us assume that the component `ts` and the `template` file is like the following snippet

```js
import {
  Component,
  Input,
  OnInit
} from '@angular/core';

import {
  ChildComponent
} from './child/child.component';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'test-app';
  val;
  clickEvt() {
    alert("clicked")
  }

  isTruthy() {
    if (( < HTMLInputElement > document.getElementById("inp1")).value == "admin" && ( < HTMLInputElement > document.getElementById("inp2")).value == "admin") {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.val = {};
    this.val.id = "id1";
    this.val.class = "abc";
  }
}
```

```html
<label>User</label>
<input {{...val}} (input)="isTruthy()" />
<br>
<label>Password</label>
<input id="inp2" (input)="isTruthy()" />
<button (click)="clickEvt()">Login</button>
<div *ngIf="isTruthy(); then truthy else falsey"></div>
<ng-template #truthy>
  <h1>Success</h1>
  <child-component [value]="isTruthy()"></child-component>
</ng-template>
<ng-template #falsey>
  <h1>Failure</h1>
  <child-component [value]="isTruthy()"></child-component>
</ng-template>
```

In the HTML template, you can notice me trying to use `{{ ...val }}`. This is my attempt to use spread operator in the template but unfortunately I get the exception

> ERROR DOMException: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '{{...val.id}}' is not a valid attribute name.

I just want to know, is there a way to use spread operator or is there an equivalent way in angular to give multiple attributes in one go which is obtained from a variable?

Comment: I do get a bit worried when people down vote without providing any valid reason

Comment: see Maryannah's answer. you can also `<input [id]="val.id" [ngClass]="val.class" (input)="isTruthy()" />`

Comment: @Eliseo, your approach would be tedious because, I may have more attributes than just `id` and `className`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot use the spread in a template (even less like you're trying).

To achieve that, you will need a reference to your template.

```html
<input #myInput (input)="isTruthy()" />
```

```js
@ViewChild('myInput', { static: true }) myInput: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>;

ngOnInit() {
  Object.assign(this.myInput.nativeElement, this.val);
}
```

Comment: Just an addition, incase of using conditional rendering like *ngIf, the value `{ static: true }` should be set to false or else the value of `myInput` would be undefined at the time of assignment.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this could be create a directive like

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[setAttr]'
})
export class AttrDirective {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  @Input() attr: any;

  ngOnInit(){
    if(this.attr){
       console.log(this.el.nativeElement)
      Object.keys(this.attr).forEach(k=>{
        this.el.nativeElement.setAttribute(k,this.attr[k])
      console.log(this.el.nativeElement)
      })
    }
  }
}
```

then apply on input like

```
<input type="text" setAttr [attr]="val">
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cr3smc-yk9pjc)

Comment: For future reference, `Object.keys.forEach` is the old way. Now you have `Object.assign` and spread with `obj = { ...obj, ...newObj }`.